# Does anyone know how to fix the lag that exists in STS 3.1 when switching to JSP's?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

We are seeing a lag of about 5-7 seconds when switching to JSP's in the latest release of STS, version 3.1.0.  Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it (other than not using the JSP editor which is not a preferable option)?  We are considering rolling back to an older release as this is such an irritation.

Also posted to Spring Forums: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?131299-STS-3-1-JSP-editor-lag

Edit: Confirmed, STS 3.1 - e3.8 does not have the JSP lag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the Eclipse 3.8 version of STS.  The 4.2 version of Eclipse is known to have some performance issues, especially when switching editors.

Comment: Thanks!  I never noticed there was two different releases when I went to download it.  Much appreciated!